# useEffect Object dependency infinite loop - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a State in Context with Object. I am running a `async` function in the `useEffect` and passing my object state as `dependency`.

> I passed the state object as dependency because i want to re-render
> the component when values of `settings` object changes.

But it causes an infinite loop.

**Update:**
Let me clear my question more.
In my `useEffect`, I am calling my async function `addTextItem()` which calls the function `finalPrice` and it updates the state, but this way it causes infinite loop.
On other hand, If i call `finalPrice` in the `useEffect` directly instead of calling `addTextItem` then there is no infinite loop but it is also updating the state, right? then how this could be. & I need a solution as i have tried everything and now totally stuck.

**Here is the code:**

```
export default function CustomizerState(props) {
    const initialText = "Hello"
    const initialSize = {
        x: REACT_APP_SIZE_X,
        y: REACT_APP_SIZE_Y
    }
    const initialTextItem = {
        id: generateID(),
        text: "Hello",
        font: fonts[0].value,
        size: initialSize,
        color: colors[0],
        backplate: "cut-sharp",
        uvPrint: false,
        quantity: 1,
        neonPrice: 0,
        backplatePrice: 0,
        neonPower: 0,
        totalPrice: 0
    }
    const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
        textItems: [],
        libraryItems: [],
        ownDesigns: [],
        accessories: [
            // My Objects here
        ],
        finalPrice: 0
    })

    const addTextItem = async () => {
        const pathLength = await textToPath(initialText, initialSize.x)
        const { backplatePrice, neonPrice, neonPower, totalPrice } = calculateSvgPrice(pathLength)
        const id = generateID()

        const newItems = [
            ...settings.textItems,
            {...initialTextItem, id, backplatePrice, neonPrice, neonPower, totalPrice}
        ]
        
        finalPrice("textItems", newItems)
    }

    const finalPrice = (itemType = null, items = null) => {
        const textItemsPrice = getTotalPrice()
        const libraryItemsPrice = getTotalPrice("libraryItems")
        const accessoriesPrice = getTotalPrice("accessories", "unitPrice")

        const finalPrice = textItemsPrice + libraryItemsPrice + parseInt(accessoriesPrice)

        if (itemType === null) {
            setSettings((prevState) => (
                {...prevState, finalPrice}
            ))
            return false
        }

        setSettings((prevState) => (
            {...prevState, [itemType]: items, finalPrice}
        ))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // It will add first initial form item
        addTextItem()
    }, [JSON.stringify(settings)])

    return (
        <CustomizerContext.Provider value={{settings, addTextItem}}>
            {props.children}
        </CustomizerContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

[image]

I have google and tried the solutions, but nothing worked for me. Can someone help me to fix this issue? I am stuck....

Comment: your useEffect ultimately changes `settings` and it has `settings` as a dependency, thus the loop. If you just want the fetch to run on first mount provide an empty dependency array (replace `}, [JSON.stringify(settings)])` with `}, [])`) otherwise find the elements of state which should actually trigger a fetch.

Comment: @pilchard bro i know that, I want to run initial form item and want my component to re-render when the values of my object changes, that's why i put the state object as dependency.

Comment: As I said, find the elements of state that should actually trigger a fetch (it needs to be a part that won't be changed by the fetch itself).

Comment: @pilchard I am confused

Comment: I don't see why you think the component won't rerender when settings object changes without putting it in the useEffect. Btw did I create this repro incorrectly, I only see one render. https://playcode.io/895838

Comment: @ZainShabir pilchared has already answered the question. Your Async function `addTextItem` updates `state` & `settings`, which in turn execute the `useEffect` again as settings object was changed.

Comment: @AseemGautam Read my question, my question is not "why" as i already know. My question is "how i can fix this"

Comment: @MichaelFlores Don't know how, but it's an infinite loop here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot that when re-rendering happens, it also runs `useEffect` obviously and it causes `setState` again and again.
I managed to fix this by creating a state named `initialItemCount` with `0` initial value. I am checking if that state value is 0 then run `addTextItem` which will add my initial form item and updates the final price, but if the value 1 then only run the `finalPrice` function.

```
const [initialItemCount, setInitialItemCount] = useState(0)
useEffect(() => {
    if (initialItemCount === 0) {
        addTextItem()
        setInitialItemCount(1)
    }
    
    if (initialItemCount === 1) {
        finalPrice()
    }
}, [JSON.stringify(settings)])
```

Finally, inner peace.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [useEffect hook documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).
The array passed in the second argument array is the dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    //hook code   
}, []);
```

The dependency array will make the hook code execute everytime any variable of the array changes. In your case you are changing the depency item `settings` in the call itself producing an infinite loop.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I have updated my question, please re-read again